# Web2py: how can I set the 'target' attribute in an SQLFORM

Tags: forms, web2py

The title says it all. I want the initial form submission to open in a new window, by having <form ... target="new">. How do I do that?

I've tried

```
SQLFORM(..., _target="new")
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SQLFORM(..., _target='_blank')
```

Comment: This turned out to be entirely my fault. It should work as suggested, but my view was creating a bespoke form using raw html, hence passing in attributes to the SQLFORM function wasn't doing anything. Many apologies.